# how to get keys of request body in node js

Tags: node.js, express, request

I am using express.
I have below code in my route file:

```
    router.post('/', function (req, res) {

        res.send(req.body);

        //res.send('Got a POST request')
    })
```

Below is few lines from my **app.js/server.js**

```
var express       = require('express');
var path          = require('path');
var favicon       = require('serve-favicon');
var logger        = require('morgan');
var cookieParser  = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser    = require('body-parser');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var adminAuth = require('./routes/adminAuth');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');


app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('hello world11')
})

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
```

To my authenticate-user route I am sending below json through rest client:

{'username':'harsimer'}

But I am unable to fetch username out of my **req.body** I have tried

> req.body.username

I am newbie to node.js and express.

Please provide some solution or reference.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you didn't configure properly `body-parser`. Could you try this snippet to use for initialization:

```
app.use( bodyParser.json() );       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     // to support URL-encoded bodies
  extended: true
}));
```

You want to use `bodyParser.json()` because as I see you expect to get input as json.

You should replace this snippet in your code with the one that I have posted above:

```
app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
```

There is similar example in [official github repo](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#expressconnect-top-level-generic).